# Сборка двух зависимых между собой проектов

Tags: ant, java

У меня два проекта на java. Один должен строится при условии того, что другой уже построен. Пытаюсь поставить зависимости в build.xml. Пишу так:

```
<target name="smthg_build" >
<exec executable="ant" dir="${project_loc}\..\..\..\src\smthgProj\">
 <arg value="build"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

Выдает странную ошибку:

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
>         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:827)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:445)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:459)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:635)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:676)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:502)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>         at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)

В чем может быть причина? Может надо как-то по другому в build.xml запись сделать?

Comment: Ещё полезно писать пути через другой слэш, иначе могут быть проблемы с переносимостью..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, ему не удалось запустить процесс ant (он не в путях).

Для запуска внешнего билд-файла используйтке таску [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html)

Например, так:

```
<ant file="external.xml" target="your_target" dir="${project_loc}\..\..\..\src\smthgProj\" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто каждый раз строить первый проект перед сборкой основного (before - имя тергета для сборки первого проекта)

```
  <target name="main" depends="before">
     ...
  </target>
```

Comment: Это годится, если они оба описаны в одном ant-проекте

Comment: это годится только таком случае:

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project default="main" basedir=".">
     <target name="build" depends="buidl.llibraries">
      // build your project
     </target>
     <target name="build.llibraries">
     <ant antfile="libraries/build.xml" target="build" />
     </target>
    </project>

когда связанный таскт делает то что нужно